# Iphone CLLocationManager horizontalAccuracy update. When? and how do I know it?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I need to display horizontalAccuracy of currentLocation on the map in my app. To do that I put a line of code in viewDidLoad(); 
(_currentLocation is CLLocationManager's location.)

```
label4Accuracy.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Accuracy: %.fm", _currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
```

And it display's accuracy.

The problem is the accuracy does not change. The horizontalAccuracy changes its accuracy if we wait enough (not always though).

What I want my app to be able to do is that it changes the accuracy and display it on the map in real time.

I expected there might be a method somewhere near CLLocationManager like;
- (CLLocationAccuracy *)horizontalAccuracyUpdated():

but there isn't. So my question is where should I put the line of code above to display the horizontalAccuracy of currentLocation that changes in accordance to the actual device's current accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your question whether you're using your own CLLocationManager instance, or getting current location from an MKMapView.

If you're just using a MKMapView, your map view is going to make a delegate call to the method `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` every time it updates the user's location, and that `userLocation` variable it passes will have a `.horizontalAccuracy` parameter that gives the accuracy in meters.

So set your view controller as the map view's delegate and implement that method and watch there for updates.

If you're actually using a CLLocationManager, the same is true except the delegate method is `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`.

Comment: thanks. What if user does not move?  (I have CLLocationManager. in .h, CLLocationManager *_locationManager; and in .m, _currentLocation = _locationManager.location;. )

Comment: oh, actually I was about to look at that delegate methods. still I need to ask 'what if the user does not move?'. is it still update accuracy?

Comment: @bicbac - CoreLocation is going to ping you with a current location fairly frequently, whether the location changes or not.